# JPA Generated Values

Tags: jpa

I generated a web CRUD application following [this page](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html)

But the wizard does not annotate primary key autoincrement field in the table(s) with @GeneratedValue.

And of course, when run the UI does not populate the autoincrement ID field with value.

So I tried looking at [this page](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)

I tried annotating the ID field(s) with @GeneratedValue but with no success.

Do I need to create table with autoincrement column first?

Comment: what is "no success" ? It isn't all about luck. If you annotate a class with `@GeneratedValue` then presumably you GENERATE THE SCHEMA. So what schema do you have? And then at runtime, what SQL is issued when inserting the object ? And that all depends on what "strategy" you have chosen for your generated value, but you don't say which you used in the end. A basic JPA documentation would tell you these things

Answer (score 0):

http://www.binarytides.com/create-autoincrement-columnfield-in-apache-derby/

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(1024),
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

this works...

then in UI remove the field for ID.